# Skeptical behavior of MoveWindow function

Tags: c++, winapi

MoveWindow(int x, int y, int nWidth, int nHeight,false) even used SetWindowPos(&wndTopMost, m_iLeft, m_iTop, m_iWidth, m_iHeight, false);

as i do not want to repaint my window, i am passing repaint parameter of MoveWindow with false. but it repaints the window.
This behavior works fine if i use LeadTool v 16, but in v16.5 MoveWindow function loose its functionality. do not know how it relates to LeadTool.

Looking forward for any help regarding of this issue

Comment: You might at least add some tags explaining what API "MoveWindow", "SetWindowPos", etc, belong to. Win32? Something else? Who knows?

Comment: More details and code would be good to get a better idea of your problem. Chances are the window is being repainted by another message/event. Try using Spy++ to log and diagnose the messages to the window to see exactly what is happening.

Answer (score 1):

It's not (only) your call when a window should be repainted. When you get an `WM_PAINT`, windows tells you that a window must be painted. "I don't want to" is not enough reason.

Comment: WM_PAINT message is sent when UpdateWindow or RedrawWindow function is called. Not sure either happens in the case of MoveWindow. I just want to set the coordinates of the window, scalling the image and redraw the window by calling ReDraw(). but MoveWindow draw the image which is not scaled. and can't call it after scalling the image.

Comment: @Akmal khan : More fundamentally, WM_PAINT is sent after InvalidateRect, which is called by quite a few operations. It doesn't really matter which operations cause it. `MoveWindow` doesn't draw anything; it couldn't.

Answer (score 0):

Are you changing the width or height of the window? If so, and if the target window has the CS_HREDRAW or CS_VREDRAW class style bits set, then resizing will cause a full repaint. (A simple move likely won't cause a repaint unless moving it uncovers part of the window that was previously hidden by some other window.)

BTW, last parameter to SetWindowPos is a set of bits, not a true/false, and the first parameter looks odd, it should be a plain HWND, not the address of a variable. See [MSDN on SetWindowPos](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633545(VS.85).aspx) for details.